# Redirect to controller codeigniter after checking validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

**I validated my form Using AJAX**

**Here is my form**

```
    <p class="login-box-msg">
    <?php 
    
      echo "<span id='error'>Sign in to start your session</span>";
    
    ?>
    </p>
     
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Employee ID" name="empid">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="pw">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-8">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" id="submit">Sign In</button>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
      </div>

  </div>
  <!-- /.login-box-body -->
  <form>
```

**Then I validated this using my ajax code**

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
 var form = $("form").serialize();
 $.ajax({
url:'verify',
data: form,
dataType:'json',
type:'post',
success: function(e)
{
  console.log(e.length);
  if(e.length < 1)
  {
    $("#error").text("Invalid Login Credentials!");
    $("#error").css("color","red");
    setTimeout(function(){
      $("#error").text("Sign in to start your session!");
      $("#error").css("color","black");
    },3000);
  }
  else
  {
   "What shoud I do"
  // I tried $("form").submit() but it just repeat 
  //$("#submit").click(function())
  }
}
});
```

On else bracket, I want to redirect to Controller on codeigniter called setCredentials() wherein it would set the credentials needed and redirect me to another page when the validation is completed (without error).

Comment: give path to your controller's function in else like this window.location ="path"

Comment: Can you add `setCredentials() ` code?

Comment: $input = $this->input->post();
$data = $this->Model->getUser($input); $_SESSION['compid'] = $data[0]['mem_compid'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $data[0]['mem_name'];
    if($data[0]['mem_acc_type']=='ENCODER')
    {
     $this->deposit(); 
    }
    else
    {
     $_SESSION['acctype'] = $data[0]['mem_acc_type'];
     $this->Admin();
    }

Comment: Unreadable. Edit your question with this code.

Answer (score 0):

In `else` part enter the below code with the url you want to redirect to:

```
window.location = "<?php echo 'your/url';  ?>";
```